# What does the shape of a multi-dimensional array signify?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

What does the shape in an n-dimensional array mean? Ex:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1]])
print(arr) # output: [[1]]
print(arr.ndim) # output: 2
print(arr.shape) # output: (1, 1)
```

Comment: "when there's only one element along one dimension" - no, there are two dimensions there.

Comment: You saw how `print(arr.ndim)` printed `2`.

Comment: Heck, you called it a 2D array yourself.

Comment: Because it's unclear.

Comment: I have refined the question now. Could you please look at the updated question and provide a suitable answer. I have not been able to ask new questions ever since this question got closed. So, it would help me a lot if you could look at opening this question again. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You yourself said that it's a 2D array that means it has 2 dimensions.
`[[1]]` is a 1 x 1 matrix that's why you get `(1, 1)` as output.

**Edit:**
*Question:* "For [[1]], there's no element along the 2nd dimension, shouldn't the size be zero along second dimension"
*Answer:* In an n dimensional array you need n coordinates to represent any element of the array. Since `[[1]]` is a 2D array you'll need 2 coordinates, `(0,0)` here, to represent the only element in the array.

Comment: According to https://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/, shape of an array is a tuple of integers giving the size of the array along each dimension. For [[1]], there's no element along the 2nd dimension, shouldn't the size be zero along second dimension.

Comment: No you're misinterpreting the meaning of an array(or matrix)

Comment: @Sid: You seem to be expecting a 1-by-1 array to have 1+1 rather than 1*1 elements. Elements don't "belong to" dimensions or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are having trouble visualizing a 1x1 array.

```
In [161]: arr = np.array([[1]])
In [162]: arr
Out[162]: array([[1]])
In [163]: arr.shape
Out[163]: (1, 1)
```

The total number of elements is 1, the product of the dimensions, 1*1:

```
In [164]: arr.size
Out[164]: 1
```

If we select 1 row, the result is a 1d array (count the [])

```
In [165]: arr[0]           # arr[0,:]
Out[165]: array([1])
```

With 2 indices, a scalar:

```
In [166]: arr[0,0]
Out[166]: 1
```

Selecting 1 column, again 1d

```
In [167]: arr[:,0]
Out[167]: array([1])
```

Or consider a 2x2 array:

```
In [168]: np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
Out[168]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

And a 2d slice:

```
In [169]: np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)[:1,:1]
Out[169]: array([[0]])
```